# Define Position based on lowest ID and Foreign Key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am currently facing the following issue: I have 1 Table with my Broker Trading Data similar to this:

```
TickerId      Id   Ticker   Shares  OrderType
...           ...  ...      ...     ...
01.01.20 ABC  5    ABC      500     Buy
01.01.20 ABC  6    ABC      250     Sell
01.01.20 ABC  7    ABC      250     Sell
...           ...  ...      ...     ...
```

The Goal is to say IF first OrderType (lowest Id where TradeId is the same) was a Buy, it's a LONG Trade ELSE a Short Trade ... output should be like this:

```
TickerId       Position   Ticker   Volume (=SUM(Shares))
...            ...        ...      ...
01.01.20 ABC   Long       ABC      1000
...            ...        ...      ...
```

What am I missing? How can I construct my Query to accomplish this task?

Thanks for looking into this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add this to all rows, use a window function.  One method is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when first_value(orderType) over (partition by tickerid order by id) = 'Buy'
             then 'Long' else 'Short'
        end) as position
from t;
```

If you just want one row per `tickerid`, you can use aggregation:

```
select tickerid,
       (case when min(case when orderType = 'Buy' then id end) = min(id)
             then 'Long' else 'Short'
        end) as position
from t
group by tickerid;
```

The logic here is that the first "Buy" id is compared to the first "id".  If they are the same, you have a "Long" trade.

Comment: Thank you this really solved my issue. I am relatively new to SQL so I was not aware that something like this is even possible :)